# Comparing patient proportions between one ER and the national average

Tags: proportion, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am looking to compare the proportion of emergency room attendances by hour of the day against a national average proportion (plus some other tests for ER variables such as referral methods and discharge destinations). Ho = no difference between the two distributions.
I was intending to use a paired t-test for the normally distributed data and a Wilcoxon signed rank test for the non-normal. I have never used the Wilcoxon using proportions, though.  Is this acceptable and if so does anyone know a good text / previous research to read?

Many thanks.